# UIButton doesn't respond to touch on first load, but works after segueing back from another view controller

Tags: ios, uibutton, segue

I'm not sure when or how this happened in my project, but it did. The main button in the middle of my initial view controller ignores all touch events when I first load the app. The buttons in my navbar on the bottom all work fine.

If I follow one of those buttons through a modal segue to another view controller and then segue back into the initial view controller, the button works perfectly.

I'm at a loss. Any idea how this could have occurred or how I could fix it?

**Update**

I can't put my finger on what, but this has something to do with my constraints. If I remove them (and my app tumbles into a mess on 3.5 inch phones), the button works at all times.

Comment: This would be easier if you posted some of your code, like maybe where you initialize the button in the view controller.

Comment: I'm assuming this is happening in iOS 7 on iPhone 5+? I've experienced something similar. Have you tried resetting first responder?

Comment: I edited the post above to say this, but I'll post it here in response: I can't put my finger on what, but this has something to do with my constraints. If I remove them (and my app tumbles into a mess on 3.5 inch phones), the button works at all times.

Comment: And yes, it's happening on iOS 7. Just in the simulator for now, though, so I can't comment on physical hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem: on the first load of the view one particular UIButton doesn't work, but if I tap on other tab bar element, launching a segue and then coming back to my home screen, it works perfectly.

My problem persists even if I remove every constraints for the view.

In my case, the POSITION of the button seems to be the cause of the issue: in the right side of the view it becomes not working, but if I move the same button on the center or left of my view it becomes available.

HELP ME/US :-(

Comment: Please add this as your comment for the question. This is not the answer/solution for the problem

Comment: I can't comment the question as I haven't enough reputation points (50 pts.)